# Capitalization in a headline

Tags: capitalization

In this headline, should the word **"more"** be capitalized?

> "Honoring Retired Employees with Twenty or **more** Years of
>   Commitment"

Comment: This question would be better received if you told us two things: (1) Where did you find this headline? Did you see it somewhere, or are you writing it? (2) What did you find when you looked elsewhere online to get this question answered? (Did you check any websites like [this one](https://capitalizemytitle.com/), for example?) As one of our [meta posts](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) says, we appreciate it when such details are furnished.

Answer (score -1):

Usually when writing a headline, you will be furnished with a **Style Guide**.

However **leading caps** being **leading caps**

> Honoring Retired Employees **W**ith Twenty **O**r **M**ore Years Of Commitment

would be a consistent way to write it.

Comment: Many (if not most) style guides would recommend lower-case letters for short prepositions like _of_, hence: _Honoring Retired Employees with Twenty or More Years of Commitment_.